# Exchange Online Account Connection refused

Tags: gnome, email, connection

I have a work email I can access via office.com. I am trying to set up an Online Account in Ubuntu 18.04 so I can have Gnome Calendar sync events.

I am selecting a Microsoft Exchange account type, enter my credentials, and after a minute or two adding the account fails stating `Code: 7 - Unexpected response from server`.

When I look at the debugging logs I can see the following messages:

```
may 29 20:17:31 carlos-ubuntu gnome-control-c[5002]: goa_ews_client_autodiscover() failed: 4 — Could not connect: Connection refused
may 29 20:18:31 carlos-ubuntu gnome-control-c[5002]: goa_ews_client_autodiscover() failed: 7 — Could not connect: Socket I/O timed out
```

I have have no issues adding this same account on my phone, for example.

I am not using Evolution nor any other local mail client. I am mostly interested in calendar events.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `outlook.office.com` as the server name in the Custom section:

[Here's a screenshot of the settings I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3AWE.png)

Comment: Used `outlook.office.com` as the server name. My error is now `Authentication failed`. Using Ubuntu 22.04.1. Any suggestions?